# 18.04: kubuntu: KDE: Power consumption is extremely high: Slowdown?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, power-management

On kubuntu 18.04, Power consumption is extremely high, anyway to slowdown?

I already disabled all effects and stopped compositor from auto-starting. My 3-cell battery lasts 4-hour browsing with Firefox on GNOME (Ubuntu 18.04) using the same settings and apps, now I get just above 1 hour on kubuntu KDE.

Output of `inxi -Fxz`

```
System:   Kernel: 4.15.0-23-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0 Console: tty 0 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: Latitude E7240 v: 00 serial: <filter>                                        
Battery    BAT0: charge: 16.6 Wh 40.4% condition: 41.2/45.1 Wh (91%) model: SMP DELL KWFFN33 status: Discharging
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-4300U (-MT-MCP-) arch: Haswell rev.1 cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9976
           clock speeds: max: 2900 MHz 1: 959 MHz 2: 1832 MHz 3: 1888 MHz 4: 1818 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@59.99hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection I218-LM driver: e1000e port: f080 bus-ID: 00:19.0
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 378.1GB (23.5% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: LITEONIT_LMT size: 128.0GB temp: 0C
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: Samsung_SSD_860 size: 250.1GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 76G used: 17G (24%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 14.04GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 59.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 198 Uptime: 17:34 Memory: 5747.1/7878.9MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: N/A
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Comment: Install `inxi` and post the output of `inxi -Fxz` here as a summary of your hardware.

Comment: @DKBose yep, above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, as it came out to be, disabling effects in system settings and disallowing auto-start of compositor is not enough and it actually had close to no effect!

The true culprit is KDE's `File Search` feature! Disable it and you are done:

[image]

Comment: Please, care to show how?

Comment: Is imgur.com blocked where you are? It is straight-forward from GUI applet in the image above. Just use desktop search to look for "file search"